# AmazonBasics Mouse with FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, mouse

I have the [AmazonBasics (Chicony) Wireless Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005EJH6Z4). The mouse works correctly under Windows. But after starting FreeBSD 10.3 (with X.Org X Server 1.17.4), clicks only have an effect after moving the mouse. Double clicking is impossible.

`dmesg | grep -i chicony` gives:

```
ugen3.3: <Chicony> at usbus3
ukbd0: <Chicony Wireless Device, class 0/0, rev 2.00/1.09, addr 3> on usbus3
uhid1: <Chicony Wireless Device, class 0/0, rev 2.00/1.09, addr 3> on usbus3
ums0: <Chicony Wireless Device, class 0/0, rev 2.00/1.09, addr 3> on usbus3
```

If I plug out the USB receiver and plug it in again, it works fine.

I don't have this problem with other mice under FreeBSD.

What should I do? Any workaround would be fine, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

amazon_mouse=`lsusb | grep  '04f2:0976' | grep -o -E 'ugen[0-9]\.[0-9]'`

if [ "x$amazon_mouse" != "x" ] ; then
  usbconfig -d $amazon_mouse reset
fi
```

This script is a successful workaround. It just resets the mouse. After running it, the mouse works correctly.

04f2:0976 is the USB-ID of the wireless receiver of the AmazonBasics (Chicony) mouse.

Answer (score 0):

should be easy enough to check what is happening using xinput.

get the device id:

```
mouseId=$(xinput -list | grep -i Point | grep "PS/2" | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -b 1-2)
```

then check the props with:

```
xinput --list-props $mouseId
```

will be interesting to see what the value of "Device Enabled" at various times (before click, after mouse move...).

EDIT:

xinput -list example:

```
mike@mike-laptop4:~$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: the variable mouseId is set to an empty string. Remember that it is an USB mouse.

Comment: what is the output of: xinput -list

Comment: the output is nothing (aside from an error message: `Usage: xinput list-props <device> [<device> ...]`)